# express.js link to an unique URL

Tags: javascript, node.js, url, express

I have a question, maybe it sounds dumb, but i couldnt find any real solution yet. I'm playing around with express.js, I have a list of links in the client html that all link to a url which specified in the server `app.get('/myURL', function(req, res){...})`, now the question is I want each link links to this URL, but the URL is unique for each link, so the links in the list dont share the same URL. Any idear?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a route that takes a parameter, like this:

```
app.get('/myURL/:parameter', user.load, function(request, result){
    // ... 
})
```

That way, `/myURL/something` and `/myURL/something_else` will both go to that route. You can then see what `parameter` they used with the variable request.params.parameter

---

See the expressjs documentation: http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.VERB